# Pass-through/export whole third party module (using __all__?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have a module that wraps another module to insert some shim logic in some functions. The wrapped module uses a settings module `mod.settings` which I want to expose, but I don't want the users to import it from there, in case I would like to shim something there as well in the future. I want them to import `wrapmod.settings`.

Importing the module and exporting it works, but is a bit verbose on the client side. It results in having to write `settings.thing` instead of just `thing`.

I want the users to be able to do `from wrapmod.settings import *` and get the same results as if they did `from mod.settings import *` but right now, only `from wrapmod import settings` is available. How to I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you're writing a module `wrapmod` that is intended to transform parts of an existing package `mod`. The specific part you're transforming is the submodule `mod.settings`. You've imported the `settings` module and made your changes to it, but even though it is available as `wrapmod.settings`, you can't use that module name in an `from ... import ...` statement.

I think the best way to fix that is to insert the modified module into `sys.modules` under the new dotted name. This makes Python accept that name as valid even though `wrapmod` isn't really a package.

So `wrapmod` would look something like:

```
import sys

from mod import settings

# modify settings here

sys.modules['wrapmod.settings'] = settings   # add this line!
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a code-generator for a thin wrapper module instead, since the `sys.module` hacking broke all IDE integration.

```
from ... import mod

# this is just a pass-through wrapper around mod.settings
__all__ = mod.__all__

# generate pass-through wrapper around mod.settings; doesn't break IDE integration, unlike manual sys.modules editing.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for thing in settings.__all__:
        print(thing + " = mod." + thing)
```

which when run as a script, outputs code that can then be appended to the end of this file.